# Is there an efficient way to estimate the common mass of two multivariate normal distributions in python?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, scipy.stats

The title says most of it. I'm using scipy.stats' `multivariate_normal` class to simulate multivariate normal distributions. Given two of them, I want to estimate the amount of their PDFs that they share in common, a value that should be between 0 and 1. Simply getting a bunch of coordinates and evaluating the PDFs of each distribution at each point using `multivariate_normal`'s built in `pdf()` function isn't great because it's not normalized and you will almost always get answers above 1. I can't find any documentation on how to change the "granularity" of how `pdf()` is evaluating the PDF. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The multivariate normal is a continuous distribution. The probability *density* function (PDF) of any continuous distribution can be greater than 1; its *integral* over any finite region must be less than or equal to 1. "the amount of their PDFs that they share in common" needs more detail to be defined mathematically. If you are still interested and can clarify what you're looking for, I may be able to help.